Rust recursive macro for creating generic
I have the following example code:
Rust Playground
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Field {
    dt: T
}

enum T {
    Int8,
    Int16,
    List(Arc<Field>)
}

trait Builder {
    fn new() -> Self where Self: Sized;
}

struct Int8Builder {}

impl Builder for Int8Builder {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

struct Int16Builder {}

impl Builder for Int16Builder {

    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}


struct ListBuilder<ValueBuilder: Builder> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<ValueBuilder>
}

impl<B: Builder> Builder for ListBuilder<B> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            _phantom: PhantomData::default()
        }
    }
}

I'm trying to have a function that generate the builder by type:

fn get_builder_bad(t: T) -> Box<dyn Builder> {
    match t {
        T::Int8 => Box::new(Int8Builder::new()),
        T::Int16 => Box::new(Int16Builder::new()),
        T::List(f) => {
            match &f.dt {
                T::Int8 => Box::new(ListBuilder::<Int8Builder>::new()),
                T::Int16 => Box::new(ListBuilder::<Int16Builder>::new()),
                T::List(f) => {
                    match &f.dt {
                        T::Int8 => Box::new(ListBuilder::<ListBuilder<Int8Builder>>::new()),
                        T::Int16 => Box::new(ListBuilder::<ListBuilder<Int16Builder>>::new()),
                        T::List(f) => {
                            match &f.dt {
                                T::Int8 => Box::new(ListBuilder::<ListBuilder<ListBuilder<Int8Builder>>>::new()),
                                T::Int16 => Box::new(ListBuilder::<ListBuilder<ListBuilder<Int16Builder>>>::new()),
                                T::List(f) => {
                                    match &f.dt {
                                        T::Int8 => Box::new(ListBuilder::<ListBuilder<ListBuilder<ListBuilder<Int8Builder>>>>::new()),
                                        T::Int16 => Box::new(ListBuilder::<ListBuilder<ListBuilder<ListBuilder<Int16Builder>>>>::new()),
// I want to increase the limit here to be at maximum depth of 20 once I use macro
                                        T::List(f) => unimplemented!("reach the limit of recursion")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

But I want to convert this to a macro to avoid the obvious duplication
I tried many things including:

macro_rules! nested_list_builder {
    // Recursive case for list types
    ($field:expr, $($wrapper_type:ty)*, $($start_token:tt)*, ,$($end_token:tt)*) => {{
        match &$field.dt {
            T::Int8 => {
                type BuilderType = $($wrapper_type $start_token)* Int8Builder $($end_token)*;
                Box::new(BuilderType::new())
            },
            T::Int16 => {
                type BuilderType = $($wrapper_type $start_token)* Int16Builder $($end_token)*;
                Box::new(BuilderType::new())
            },
            T::List(f) => {
                nested_list_builder!(f , $($wrapper_type)* ListBuilder, $($start_token)*<, >$($end_token)*)
            }
        }
    }};
}

fn get_builder(t: T) -> Box<dyn Builder> {
    match t {
        T::Int8 => Box::new(Int8Builder::new()),
        T::Int16 => Box::new(Int16Builder::new()),
        T::List(f) => nested_list_builder!(f, ListBuilder, <, >)
    }
}

There are 2 problems:

this fails with:

error: local ambiguity when calling macro `nested_list_builder`: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs tt ('start_token') or 1 other option.
   --> macros_should_work/src/generic_recursion_hell.rs:233:61
    |
233 |         T::List(f) => nested_list_builder!(f, ListBuilder, <, >)

which is reasonable as comma is also a token but I don't have a workaround (I tried moving the $start_token variable to be before the type but faced different error)

It will fail on recursion limit as there is no termination case (I think the solution is to pass X expressions and every call to itself, remove one until we have none and it will match an empty case but I don't really know how to do it)

I feel like the solution is using Incremental TT munchers or Push-down Accumulation or a combination of both

So I was able to make it work by using helper type for wrapping the expanded macro type and paste + seq-macro
macro_rules! nested_list_concrete_case_helper {
    ($wrapper_type: ident, $unique_ident: tt, $builder: ident) => {
        {
            paste::paste! {
                type [<BuilderType $unique_ident>] = $wrapper_type<$builder>;
                Box::new([<BuilderType $unique_ident>]::new())
            }
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! nested_list_builder {
    // Helper to have a limit on the recursion without to pass unique identifiers to the macro
    ($field:expr, $wrapper_type: ident, $limit: literal) => {
        seq!(N in 0..=$limit {
            nested_list_builder!(
                $field,
                $wrapper_type,
                #( N, )*
            )
        })
    };

    // Last case for the recursion when reached the limit
    ($field:expr, $wrapper_type: ident, ) => {
        match &$field.dt {
            T::Int8 => nested_list_concrete_case_helper!($wrapper_type, Int8, Int8Builder),
            T::Int16 => nested_list_concrete_case_helper!($wrapper_type, Int16, Int16Builder),
            T::List(f) => {
                unimplemented!("reach the limit of recursion")
            }
        }
    };

    // Recursive case, will call itself each time removing one from the tail by matching the `$unique_ident` token
    ($field:expr, $wrapper_type: ident, $unique_ident: tt, $($tail:tt)*) => {{
            match &$field.dt {
                T::Int8 => nested_list_concrete_case_helper!($wrapper_type, $unique_ident, Int8Builder),
                T::Int16 => nested_list_concrete_case_helper!($wrapper_type, $unique_ident, Int16Builder),
                T::List(f) => {
                    paste::paste! {
                        type [<BuilderType $unique_ident>]<T> = $wrapper_type<ListBuilder<T>>;
                        nested_list_builder!(f, [<BuilderType $unique_ident>], $($tail)*)
                    }
                }
            }
    }};
}


fn get_builder(t: T) -> Box<dyn Builder> {
    match t {
        T::Int8 => Box::new(Int8Builder::new()),
        T::Int16 => Box::new(Int16Builder::new()),
        T::List(f) => {
            nested_list_builder!(f, ListBuilder, 50)
        }
    }
}


